# Why the positional embeddings for a specific position i, for each embedding element is different

Tags: transformers, embeddings

for this formulas `PE(pos,2i)=sin(pos/(10000^(2i/modelDimension)))` and `PE(pos,2i+1)=cos(pos/(10000^(2i/modelDimension)))`

we know `PE for position i` follows: `[sin(i/denominator[0]),cos(i/denominator[0]), sin(i/denominator[1]),cos(i/denominator[1]), sin(i/denominator[2]),cos(i/denominator[2]),...]`. note each element here is a proposed positional embedding element for an embedding element.

My question is why the positional embeddings for a specific position i, for each embedding element is different? how does it make sense to shift each embedding value to a different place in embedding space, for a specific position i?

in other words, why they `treat` each positional embedding along embeddings dimension `differently`? they all `belong to same position`, so why they are `not assigned to the same value` (note the denominator elements (denominator[0],denominator[1],...) are different for each embedding element)

I also understand that these are learnable parameters, which I think they shouldnt be, because this way may lead to overfitting, but that other whole story, but anyway we should try to make first meaningful assignments to them, rather expect the network to learn it by itself.

in general are there better positional embeddings which make more reasonable sense?

Answer (score 1):

Positional embeddings use good old [Fourier transformations used in time-series regression models](https://otexts.com/fpp3/useful-predictors.html#fourier-series). The denominator controls the period of the sin and cos functions. For example, in time-series data, the denominator could be 7 for the weekly period, or 365.5 for a yearly one. In the embeddings, the denominators are learnable parameters, so the model can learn different periods that work best for the data. Using a time-series example again, it could learn that for specific data weekly and quarterly periods work best, but monthly are unnecessary.

Comment: thanks for ur answer. u provided valuable knowledge. but my 1st question is about reason why they treat each positional embedding along embeddings dimension differently? they all belong to same position, so why they are not assigned the same value (note the denominator elements are different for each embedding element)

Comment: @FarhangAmaji using the example above, if you have different denominators you can use weekly periods *and* quarterly, if you had only one you would need to pick one.

Comment: I am separating the questions in order to reduce the confusion, wait a moment

Comment: sorry, I tried to explain my questions much better this time, it seemed that they hardships for understanding but just closing them without explanations, wont give me insights what to explain better.
this is the second question : https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/618530/why-the-positional-embeddings-for-different-positions-are-not-confined-to-pi

Comment: can u answer them separately, I think u have misunderstood my question, if not please explain it a bit better. thanks

Comment: @FarhangAmaji embeddings create features to be used by the rest of the model. So for example, embedding with denominator 7 creates a weekly feature, while embedding with denominator 365.5 creates a yearly feature. With single denominator you would not be able to create multiple features.

Comment: first of all, do u mean, if the embedding size was sth like 7 also if each position was temporal data for the weekly time also each embedded dimension was particularly consisted the values for each day of week, then we could have interpreted that as this positional embeddings can play a role in case of signifying the difference in between days of a week?
I can recall sth from `n-beats` algorithm which used same thing for seasonality, but in case of nlp or other things which are not superspecific like last example, it seems embeddings are all belong to a single position (single) word, so____

Comment: so pushing them to different locations(by adding different positional embeddings) doesnt seem to make sense!!!
but before everything, did I guess use case of different positional embeddings for ur example correct? did u mean it can make sense if the data is that specific ( the embedding size was sth like 7 also if each position was temporal data for the weekly time also each embedded dimension was particularly consisted the values for each day of week)? I meant I think u have said `it can make sense if the case is super specific`.

Comment: @FarhangAmaji in time-series data you also pass the position (time) to create multiple features. For example, you would create 2D embeddings for weekly & yearly periods with `denominator = [7, 365.5]`, which would create two features (in fact four, since it's sin & cos).

Comment: which if the case if the embedding elements each belong to a different day, they are litterally different data, so its reasonable if they are assigned to different positional embeddings. in that case the only the shape of data is different, instead of putting all day in a sequence, we have put them in sth like embedding each showing different day of a week

Comment: which if the case if the embedding elements each belong to a different day, they are litterally different data, so its reasonable if they are assigned to different positional embeddings. in that case the only the shape of data is different, instead of putting all day in a sequence, we have put them in sth like embedding each showing different day of a week

Comment: @FarhangAmaji I do not understand what you mean by your comments. With the embeddings, you pass as input the position indexes ($n$ of them) and get as a result $n \times 2k$ matrix, where $k$ is the size of the embeddings (`len(denominator)`). You transform the indexes into $2k$ features.

Comment: first tell me, did I get it right? `it can make sense if the case is super specific`?? lets just make cases. `case1`: the data is a sequence of weekly and each embedding is a value of a day in week. `case2`: data also is a sequence of weekly but each embedding is not particularly a value of a day in week.

does having different donimator values for each embedding element make sense in both cases or only makes sense for case 1?

Comment: I hope I have not bothered u, but I didnt understand the things u said, now I tried to elaborate on what I have not understand, by even making cases. I hope u tell me, more about it, but if u dont thanks anyway.

Comment: @FarhangAmaji I'm sorry but I do not understand what you mean by this. In time-series you use the time index as input to create the feature, in NLP you use the index of the word as input. I do not understand what you mean by those cases.

Comment: so please just answer what u meant (the comment of mine starting with `first tell me, did I get it right?`). ofc if u like to.

Comment: @FarhangAmaji I don't understand what you mean, so cannot answer.

Comment: thanks u so much dear Tim